# Where can I download the Northwind sample database for SQLite?

Tags: sql, linux, database, sqlite, northwind

After looking at:

[Where can I download Northwind database for Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2585643/262852)

it looks like the best place for Northwind data, outside of the Microsoft itself, is:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/northwindextended/downloads

to what extent does this raw data match the Microsoft data?  Is there any advantage in downloading directly from Microsoft?

I'll be using either MySQL or SQLite, mostly on Linux.  The Microsoft site at least emphasized their SQL Server, of course.

Comment: I would expect it to match but I have not gone through the matching exercise.  Seems pretty silly if they didn't.  I am also curious to know the answer if anyone has done the work..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See https://github.com/jpwhite3/northwind-SQLite3

"All the TABLES and VIEWS from the MSSQL-2000 version have been converted to Sqlite3 and included here. Also included are two versions prepopulated with data - a small version and a large version"

Comment: Does this sample database contain blob images?

Comment: @Ashwin - Categories.Picture and Employees.Photo

Answer (score 3):

You can download a version of sqlite3 database from

https://code.google.com/archive/p/northwindextended/downloads

Advantage:  It is available immediately.  Click and use.

If it's simply to get a sample database for general testing, then just use what's immediately available. If you require an exact copy to match testing results (for instance), then download and convert MS data yourself to ensure exactness since the file's header indicates modifications and added foreign keys and contains no other certification of content.  *You really need to answer this for yourself based on your own requirements.*

Without knowing anything about the conversion process, I would at least guess that the date values are not precisely the same since sqlite has no native DateTime type, rather such values would have needed to be converted to string values and/or Julian numeric values.  Of course the values themselves may represent the same dates and times, but processing of query data would certainly require special handling.  BLOB values for images should also produce the same images, but retrieving and using those values will likely be different than getting them from other databases.  I suppose there could be other data values/types that different handling would apply since sqlite really has no distinct, strict numeric types, rather just type affinities.